# CollectionView using Observable Collection is not updating images

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

The observable collection is not updating, I am alos using a collectionview to create a grid layout similar to Instagram, when I add an Image i want the UI to update

```
if(photo.Success)
{
   Photos.Add(new Photo { PhotoPath = photo.PhotoPath});

   OnPropertyChanged(new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Photos)));
}
```

```
              <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackLayout>
                            <ffimageloading:CachedImage
                                Source="{Binding PhotoPath, Converter={StaticResource Key=path}}"
                                Aspect="AspectFill"
                                HeightRequest="130">
                                <ffimageloading:CachedImage.GestureRecognizers>
                                    <TapGestureRecognizer
                                        CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
                                        Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference dash}, Path=BindingContext.SelectedCommand}"/>
                                </ffimageloading:CachedImage.GestureRecognizers>
                                </ffimageloading:CachedImage>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
```

```
 public class PhotoPathConverter:IValueConverter
    {
        private string pathUrl = "https://photobucket-resized.s3.af-south-1.amazonaws.com/";

        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            string path = string.Empty;

            if(value != null)
            {
               path = pathUrl + (string)value; 
            }
            return path;
        }
        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

App.xaml

```
<converters:PhotoPathConverter x:Key="path"/>

public ObservableCollection<Photo> Photos { get; set; }
```

The funny thing is that when I put on a breakpoint, with that slight delay it works

The observable collection is not updating, I am alos using a collectionview to create a grid layout similar to Instagram, when I add an Image i want the UI to update

Comment: `Converter={StaticResource Key=path}` doesn’t look right. That doesn’t say which converter to use.

Comment: The naming is a bit weird but that's the key "path" I set it on App class style. The converter does get called however it does not update

Comment: ok. For me to understand what is happening, please add the code or xaml that makes key "path" refer to that converter. (Its probably not relevant, but seeing the whole code involved helps me be sure I'm not overlooking something.)

Comment: Also, add declaration of `Photos`.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve okay I've added,  Photos = new ObservableCollection<Photo>(); in my constructor. Also I've noticed when I add a breakpoint  that slight delay it works, it updates the UI

Comment: Good. `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread` in my answer should fix it then. If not, I'll show a slightly more complicated way, that adds a fraction of a second delay.

Comment: Hi @ToolmakerSteve I tried the Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread still nothing.

Comment: Added version with slight delay. If that doesn't fix it, then there must be something about ffimageloading. Unless someone else comes along with a better idea, you'll need to make a public github with just enough in it to run, and see the symptom.

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: `OnPropertyChanged` only matters when you **set** a property. When an `ObservableCollection` changes, the event that is triggered is `CollectionChanged`. This is done for you automatically.

---

First, for XAML to see changes in a collection, it must be `ObservableCollection`, not `List`.

Second, Photos must be a *property* (get/set), not a field.

The declaration should look something like this:

```
public ObservableCollection<MyModel> Photos { get; } = new ObservableCollection<MyModel>();
```

(Alternatively, you can do `Photos = new ...` in your constructor.)

or if you will "set" Photos later, like this:

```
public ObservableCollection<MyModel> Photos {
    get => _photos;
    set {
        _photos = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
private ObservableCollection<MyModel> _photos;
```

---

If that wasn't the problem, then see if this works any better. Change:

```
if (photo.Success)
{
   Photos.Add(new Photo { PhotoPath = photo.PhotoPath});

   OnPropertyChanged(new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Photos)));
}
```

to

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => {
    if (photo.Success)
    {
       Photos.Add(new Photo { PhotoPath = photo.PhotoPath});

       //OnPropertyChanged(new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Photos)));
    }
});
```

Explanation: Sometimes changes to UI-bound values don't work as expected, because Xamarin (or the native platform OS) is internally at a place in code that doesn't behave well.

Wrapping with BeginInvoke *queues* the code to run on MainThread (UI thread), after Xamarin finishes what it is currently doing. (Xamarin returns from event handler or command in which you have that code.)

I haven't determined under what conditions this is necessary. (Such code is already "on MainThread", so its not due to "being on wrong thread".)

---

In more extreme situations, adding a slight delay helps:

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () => {
    if (photo.Success)
    {
        await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(200);
        Photos.Add(new Photo { PhotoPath = photo.PhotoPath});
    }
});
```

Comment: I think I know what the issue is. Because I have a different AWS bucket for Thumbnails, I believe when I upload without the delay the image is being called before it gets transferred to the  Thumbnail bucket by the lambda function I am using. I guess I will just use the original bucket cause that works fine. Thank you so much for your help @ToolmakerSteve

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to get around this issue using a UriImageSource

```
PhotoPath = new UriImageSource
{
  Uri = new Uri(_http_resized + Object.PhotoPath),
  CachingEnabled = true,
  CacheValidity = TimeSpan.FromDays(2)
};
```

Because I wanted my images cached which makes it kind of hard if you want a user to update it. I created another instance of UriImageSource with no caching then set caching after the update

```
PhotoPath = new UriImageSource
{
  Uri = new Uri(_http_resized + Object.PhotoPath),
  CachingEnabled = false,
  CacheValidity = TimeSpan.FromDays(0)
};

Some code.....

PhotoPath.CachingEnabled = true;
PhotoPath.CacheValidity = TimeSpan.FromDays(2)
```